# Detecting clicks on QTreeView icons

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreeview

I have a *QTreeView* in which some items are decorated with an icon. The items could be in any column of the TreeView.

I wish to know how to detect mouse clicks on an icon. I can use the view's *mousePressEvent()* to detect a mouse press, I can check whether an icon is present in the clicked item by calling the model's *data()* method with *Qt.DecorationRole* to see whether I get an empty *QVariant* back, and I can query the size of the icon using the view's *iconSize()* method. But I have no way of knowing the co-ordinates of the icon within the item's visual rectangle.

PS. Other SO questions relating to QTreeView decorations usually refer to the tree *collapse* and *expand* icons, and have no bearing on this question.

Comment: The problem is to detect the mouse click - in my case I will be performing an action depending on the data in the model, but that is irrelevant to the issue. The second part is related because the position of the icon within an item is controlled by its styling - but I see your point that it adds nothing to the question, so I will remove it. Thanks.

Comment: Just place an icon into separate column, if it's possible. Otherwise you need to handle a lot of different cases, you get a universal answer. Because icons may be with different size or location. I agree with @eyllanesc - you may look at source code of `drawControl` and somehow predict the icon location.

Answer (score 2):

The logic is to have 2 data:

- The position of the mouse where you click, and that can be obtained in the editorEvent method of delegate.
- The position of the icon that is obtained using the StyleOptionViewItem and the QStyle used for painting.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        ret = super().editorEvent(event, model, option, index)
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.initStyleOption(option, index)
            widget = option.widget
            style = (
                widget.style() if widget is not None else QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
            )
            icon_rect = style.subElementRect(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemDecoration, option, widget
            )
            if icon_rect.contains(event.pos()):
                print("icon clicked")
        return ret


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(128, 128)
    pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.green)
    icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    for i in range(5):
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(f"item-{i}")
        item.setIcon(icon)
        item.setEditable(False)
        model.appendRow(item)
        for j in range(6):
            child_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(f"item {i}{j}")
            child_item.setIcon(icon)
            child_item.setEditable(False)
            item.appendRow(child_item)
    w = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    w.setModel(model)
    w.expandAll()
    delegate = Delegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I tried to use this as a means to click the expand/collapse "icon" in my `QTreeView`, but of course it turns out that such screen "features" don't qualify as icons for the purpose of this `QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemDecoration` identification. Instead, you have to find the `QTreeView.visualRect()` for the `QModelIndex` and kind of do the mouse click at a promising `QPoint` in the left of that box (at least that's the best I've been able to find so far).

Answer (score 1):

In c++ QT this can be achieved through this method , must be similar in python also.

If you draw the icon in paint you must know the location.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#editorEvent.

```
bool PixelDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QMouseEvent* mouseEvent = (QMouseEvent*) event;
    QPoint p =  mouseEvent->pos();   // Position of mouse click.    
    
    return false;
}
```